# android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE not recognised

Tags: xamarin.android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have a project that checks the network connectivity state like this:

```cs
public void GetStatus ()
{
    ConnectivityManager oManager;
    ConnectivityState eState;
    //
    oManager = (ConnectivityManager)m_oContext.GetSystemService (Activity.ConnectivityService);
    //
    if (oManager.ActiveNetworkInfo == null)
        Connected = false;
    else
        Connected = oManager.ActiveNetworkInfo.IsConnected;
    //
    // Get the current connection state
    if (!Connected) 
        eState = ConnectivityState.NotConnected;
    else if (oManager.GetNetworkInfo (ConnectivityType.Mobile).GetState () == NetworkInfo.State.Connected) 
        eState = ConnectivityState.Roaming;
    else if (oManager.GetNetworkInfo (ConnectivityType.Wifi).GetState () == NetworkInfo.State.Connected)
        eState = ConnectivityState.WiFi;
    else
        eState = ConnectivityState.Other;
    //
    State = eState;
    //
    if (StatusUpdated != null)
        StatusUpdated ();
}
```

This worked fine when running from Xamarin Studio, but now I've moved my project over to Visual Studio 2012 it doesn't pick up the permission set in the manifest. Here's what I have in the manifest:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="MyApp.Android">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="My App"></application>
</manifest>
```

I created the manifest file by going to the properties of the solution and choosing to create it from there, then checked the checkbox for `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` yet still when I run from VS2012 I get an exception saying the device doesn't have the permission. Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Our project uses the same permission without any issues, and we use VS2012.  Did you try adding a different permission to the manifest to see if it's an issue specific to ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE or not?  For instance, try android.permission.CALL_PHONE and see if you still get an exception

Comment: So, finally got the time to come back to this. Seems it was an issue with how I transfered the project from Xamarin Studio to Visual Studio. After creating a simple app from scratch within VS2012 to test this permission it worked fine. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear you got it working!